# Eloquent retrieve data from another model on runtime

Tags: mysql, laravel, database, eloquent

I have two tables;

Data

- id
- name

Custom_data

- id
- data_id (references id on Data)
- customer_id (references id on Customers)
- name

When I retrieve all items from the database (via for example Data::all()) as Customer X then I want to retrieve values from 'Custom_data' **in favor** of the data in table 'Data' where the *customer_id* matches X

Example:
*Data* contains *name* 'John Doe' with *id* 1

*Custom_data* contains a record with *data_id* 1 and *name* 'Jane Doe' and *customer_id* X

When retrieving the models I want to see Jane Doe instead of John Doe. Can this be done on a Model level in Eloquent? This is just a simple example, in our application we have multiple columns that need to be retrieved (firstname, lastname, street, etc. etc.)

How I am currently retrieving the fields is like this:

```
public function getNameAttribute($name) {

$customData = CustomData::where('customer_id', $this->customer_id)->where('data_id', $this->id)->first();
if(null != $customData) {
  return $customData->name;
 } else {
  return $name;
 }
}
```

Comment: you can create relationship in model file and can use it easily in run time to get another model's related data

Comment: Thanks Harsh, but that means I would need to use a relation for this. I would like to do it in the boot() method or something if possible. Otherwise, how should I filter out the results in the end?

Comment: To make sure I understand before giving u a suggestion, you want to swap all duplicates based on id from data into custom_data?

Comment: Hi Nikola, I updated my question with an example piece of code to achieve what I want but I want a more general solution for it

Answer (score 1):

Here' how you can do it:

In your **Data.php** modal file you need to add relationship:

```
public function CustomData(){
    return $this->hasOne(CustomData::class);
}
```

Now, you can use **CustomData** function on eloquent record anywhere in Controller or View at runtime to get related data.

Another approach is to get data on condition basis:

```
$users = User::select('users.id', 'users.username', 'users.active', 'users.parent_id', 'parent.username as parent_username')
            ->selectRaw("CASE WHEN GROUP_CONCAT(roles.name) = 'student' THEN user_profiles.secondary_email ELSE users.email END as email");
```

I've used this type of solution for another purpose where I needed to use email on condition basis.

Comment: Thanks @harsh-dosi What I WAS doing was this:


`public function getNameAttribute($name) {
        $customData = CustomData::where('customer_id', $this->customer_id)->where('data_id', $this->id)->first();
        if(null != $customData) {
            return $customData->name;
        } else {
            return $name;
        }
    }`

Because I just want to retrieve the data INSTEAD of the original. But I need to have this for ALL attributes. 
Any thoughts? Ideas?

Comment: another method is to fetch records on condition bases like this -- $users = User::select('users.id', 'users.username', 'users.active', 'users.parent_id', 'parent.username as parent_username')
            ->selectRaw("CASE WHEN GROUP_CONCAT(roles.name) = 'student' THEN user_profiles.secondary_email ELSE users.email END as email")

Comment: I've edited answer and added another aproach @BossNL

Comment: Thanks @Harsh - but I want to do a Data::all() and then also retrieve Jane Doe instead of John Doe. Is this possible? It must be on a Model level and not in the controller.

Answer (score 0):

first you need to define relation in model

```
class DataModel extends Model{
    ...
    public function customData()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(CustomDataModel::class,"data_id");
    }
}
```

now you have access to this data.

```
$data = DataModel::with("customData")->first();
$data->name; // John Doe
$data->customData->name; // Jane Doe
```

Comment: I understand what you are saying. But what when I do DataModel::all() ? It will not return Jane Doe because I am not calling the relation. DataModel::with('customData') will return the relations but then the original data will be leading. I want to see 'Jane Doe' even when I do DataModel::all()

Answer (score 0):

Allright, I think I nailed this one.

I made a hasOne relation in my Data model:

```
public function custom_data() {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Models\CustomData', 'data_id')->where('customer_id', $customer_id);
    }
```

After that, I could fairly easily add the correct accessors like so:

```
public function getNameAttribute($name) {
        return null != $this->custom_data ? $this->custom_data->name : $name;
    }
```

If the custom data attribute has been set, we'll return that. If not, we'll return the original attribute.